# Why is $\mathbf{C}=(\lambda\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{A})^+(\lambda\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{A})+\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^\top$ symmetric idempotent?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\mathbf A\mathbf x=\lambda\mathbf x$ be the eigenvalue equation for a real symmetric $\mathbf A \in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$. We now define $\mathbf B=(\lambda\mathbf I-\mathbf A)$ and $\mathbf C=\mathbf B^+\mathbf B +\mathbf x\mathbf x^\top$, where $\mathbf B^+$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse. In addition, $\mathbf x^\top\mathbf{x}=1$ holds true. Show that $\mathbf C$ is symmetric and idempotent.

I am really stuck on this one. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the Moore-Penrose seudoinverse?

Comment: According to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse the product is symmetric by definition. For idempotent, my guess is to use properties 1. and 2. of the wikipedia article. Do you have a different definition?

Comment: @user251257. Yes I mean $\mathbf{xx}^\top$. Updated the question.

Comment: @WillM. My definition is the same and I know that $\mathbf B^+ \mathbf B$  is symmetric, but what about $\mathbf{xx}^\top$?

Comment: $(xx^\intercal)^\intercal=x^{\intercal\intercal}x^\intercal=xx^\intercal$

Comment: You **must** say in your text that $x$ is such that $\|x\|=1$. Otherwise, it is not exact

Comment: @JeanMarie My apologies. I have updated the question.

Comment: @mkleo_10 Check out my edit.

Comment: Is there any application for this problem or it's just a curious fact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $x$ is a the normalized eigenvector it follows:

\begin{align}
  C^2 = B^+ \underbrace{B B^+ B}_{=B}
      + B^+ \underbrace{B x}_{= 0} x^T
      + \underbrace{xx^T B^+ B}_{= xx^T B^T (B^+)^T = 0}
      + x\underbrace{x^T x}_{= \|x\|^2 = 1} x^T
      = B^+ B + xx^T
      = C
\end{align}

**Addendum:** I found a simple proof for [JeanMarie's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2250372/99220) conjecture: If $A$ is symmetric, invertible and has no double eigenvalues, then $C=I$.

Since $A$ is real symmetric there exists an orthogonal matrix $P$ with $PAP^{-1} = D$, where $D=\text{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ is the diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of $A$.

Now without loss of generality let $\lambda = \lambda_1$ be the first eigenvalue of $A$ and $x$ the appropriate normalised eigenvector. Moreover note that

$$ (\lambda I - A)^+ = \big(P^{-1}(\lambda I - D) P\big)^+ = P^{-1}(\lambda I - D)^+ P $$

Thus
\begin{align}
C = B^+B + xx^T &=\big(P^{-1}(\lambda I - D)^+(\lambda I - D) P + xx^T\big) \\
&= P^{-1}\big((\lambda I - D)^+(\lambda I - D)  + (Px)(Px)^T\big)P \\
&= P^{-1}P = I
\end{align}

Because

$$(\lambda I - D)^+(\lambda I - D) = \small{
\begin{pmatrix} 0 &&& \\&1/\lambda_2&&\\&&\ddots&\\&&&1/\lambda_n\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 0 &&& \\&\lambda_2&&\\&&\ddots&\\&&&\lambda_n\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 0 &&& \\&1&&\\&&\ddots&\\&&&1\end{pmatrix}} $$

And

$$(Px)(Px)^T = e_1 e_1^T = \begin{pmatrix} 1 &&& \\&0&&\\&&\ddots&\\&&&0\end{pmatrix} $$
Since $Ax=\lambda_1 x \iff PAP^{-1} P x = \lambda_1 P x \iff DPx = \lambda_1 P x \implies Px = \pm e_1$

Comment: The LaTeX implementation here doesn't allow mathtools? \mathclap would be pretty handy here

Comment: I don't agree : the 4th term is not $xx^Txx^T$ but $x^Txx^Tx$. Besides, I don't understand why $xx^T B^+ B = xx^T B^T (B^+)^T$ ?

Comment: Last time I checked $(xx^T)^2 = (xx^T) (xx^T) = xx^Txx^T$.  The other thing you mentioned is a consequence of $B^+B$ being symmetric, which is just a property of the Moore-Penrose inverse.

Comment: [+1] Thank you for your answer. (for the first remark, I was working with the initial version of the text).

Comment: @Hyperplane Thank you for your answer. This piece might it make into my master thesis. Although it might sound unusual, I prefer to cite such things I have not come up with myself. May I cite your user name in my work?

Comment: @Hyperplane Have you seen the answer I just posted ?

Comment: @mkleo_10 Don't send to print your master thesis before having seen my answer :)

Comment: @mkleo_10 I don't think this is necessary since it's really just a direct 1 line computation. One additional thing that I want to point out to you though is that $A$ doesn't even need to be symmetric, since $B^+ B$ is always symmetric (or hermitian), even if $B$ isn't. However in the general case this will lead to the appearance of complex eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, in a large majority of cases (see our exchange with @Hyperplane) ** $C $ the identity matrix.** Thus, in particular it is symmetrical and idempotent.

This is attested by many simulations using random matrices of different orders with the following Matlab program:

> ```
> clear all;close all
> n=3;A=rand(n);
> A=A'+A; % made symmetrical
> [P,D]=eig(A);L=D(1,1); % first eigenvalue 
> x=P(:,1); % associated (normalized) eigenvector
> B=L*eye(n)-A; 
> C=pinv(B)*B+x*x'
> ```

I confess that I have at present no proof of this property..

Comment: The idempotence holds true if $\mathbf A$ is a symmetric matrix, as I stated in my question.

Comment: You should have said in your text that the eigenvector has to be normalized.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, but this is simply a consequence of the fact that the random matrices you generate are all invertible. For instance it doesn't hold for $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0\\ 0&1&1\\0&1&1 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @JeanMarie actually it doesn't even hold for all invertible matrices. Take for instance $A=I_2$. The only case when it does hold is if $A$ has $n$ distinct non-zero eigenvalues (i.e. it is invertible and has no double eigenvalues). The random matrices you produce almost always have this property.

Comment: @Hyperplane Thank you for your very interesting comment. Nevertheless, it seems that all the cases you mention have globally a probability 0 to occur. I mean that the property I have mentionned still holds  with an "almost surely" (for a certain measure), don't you think ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes that should indeed be the case. Even better, I found a simple proof for your conjecture and added it to my answer.

Comment: @Hyperplane Very well !Yes, add it to your answer. I will refer to it in my answer.